# What is a package descriptor?

Tags: java, eclipse, package, javadoc, descriptor

Came accross this term while looking at how to create a package-info.java file. 
Heres the original:

> 1.Create a file package-info.java in your package to document
>     2.Add the package descriptor
>     3.Add a comment (/** ...*/) before the package declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's just saying put the package statement. Like

```
/**
 * stuff here
 */
package yourpackage;
```

Answer (score -1):

It's usefull for adding elements to be added to javadoc as a description of the package.

See [this example](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/whats-package-info-java-for/)